# I Can't show my database tables through migration command on powershell terminal (Windows 10)

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I tried to run: php artisan migrate

Also to connect to MySQL using terminal on Windows.

I Got this error:

```
  SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it (SQL: select * from information_schema.tables where table_schema = firstproject and table_name = migrations and table_type = 'BASE TABLE')

  at C:\Users\ekind\Desktop\LaravelTest\FirstProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connection.php:692
    688▕         // If an exception occurs when attempting to run a query, we'll format the error
    689▕         // message to include the bindings with SQL, which will make this exception a
    690▕         // lot more helpful to the developer instead of just the database's errors.
    691▕         catch (Exception $e) {
  ➜ 692▕             throw new QueryException(
    693▕                 $query, $this->prepareBindings($bindings), $e
    694▕             );
    695▕         }
    696▕     }

  1   C:\Users\ekind\Desktop\LaravelTest\FirstProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDOException::("SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it")

  2   C:\Users\ekind\Desktop\LaravelTest\FirstProject\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Database\Connectors\Connector.php:70
      PDO::__construct()
```

.env file:

```
DB_CONNECTION=mysql
DB_HOST=localhost
DB_PORT=3306          
DB_DATABASE=firstprojectdb      
DB_USERNAME=root  
DB_PASSWORD=Ekin1234
```

I tried to change my DB_HOST to "localhost" but it didn't work.

When I want to show databases it shows those;

```
mysql> show databases;
+--------------------+
| Database           |
+--------------------+
| firstproject       |
| firstprojectdb     |
| information_schema |
| mysql              |
| performance_schema |
| sakila             |
| sys                |
| world              |
+--------------------+
```

But even if I create tables like these it didn't see

```
public function up()

{
    Schema::create('posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id'); // İdentity(1,1) İd int
        $table->string('title');  // title (Create a new string column on the table.)
        $table->mediumText('body'); // body  (Create a new medium text column on the table.)
        $table->timestamps();
    });
```

As you see;

```
mysql> show tables;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

I even delete the extension of "`extension=pdo_mysql`" but it didn't work to me.

PLS HELP ME GUYS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make sure that your server is running, if you are working on the localhost check your Xampp that the server and mysql both are running. [see image here make sure these are not stopped like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ea4X0.png) First run: `php artisan migrate` and then if you get the error check your .env, that you have provided the correct details or not.

Note: localhost by default have no password, make sure that you have the same password and database name.

Furthermore, if the above doesn't work for you then try the below commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
```

and then:

```
php artisan migrate
```

Comment: I'm not using Xampp, I downloaded Mysql Manager directed from MYSQL site. Should I download it essentially ?

Comment: download Xampp, the physical layout would be more helpful, and remember place your project folder into the xampp/htdocs folder, so that It will work.